# control a parent 5 levels back from the checkbox when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, css

As you can see in the HTML, the checkbox is buried 5 levels inside the class I want to affect.

```js
$(".icheckbox").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest(".gallery-item").addClass("active");
  } else {

  }
});
```

```css
a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="gallery-item" href="#">
  <div class="image">
    <ul class="gallery-item-controls">
      <li>
        <label class="check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</a>
```

What I want is to add an `.active` class to the `gallery-item` class when the checkbox is checked on and remove it when is off(unchecked). But I can't find my way that far back with Jquery and to make matters worse, I can't control it depending on the checked attr because the checked attr doesn't get added when it's checked. Weird.

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/pNgdeJ). If you got it right, the gray area should turn red on and aff with the checkbox

Thanks fellas

Comment: `$(this).closest(".gallery-item")` will find the containing item.

Comment: There's no reason to use codepen for your example. Post the code here as a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)

Comment: @Barmar so without the checked attr, how can I conditionally do this? Oh, and I like CODEPEN cause I keep coming back to old code fixes and stuff like that. I pay for it, might as well use it.

Comment: When you click on a checkbox, the checked *property* is changed, not the attribute. Where is your Javascript, I don't see it on the codepen.

Comment: I took it off cause I wrote it based on the checked state but no state is being recorded so it was pointless

Comment: You need to use a click handler: `$(".icheckbox").click(...)`. Inside that, you need to test `this.checked`, and then use the above selector to find the containing item, and make whatever changes you want to it.

Comment: How are we supposed to tell what you're doing wrong if you take it off? It's not pointless to show your incorrect code, that's the whole point of this site. You post the wrong code, and we show you how to fix it.

Comment: Alright, I'll add it back on, although you gave me a pretty good idea how to put it together. but let me check first.

Comment: Post your code in the question, not at another site, especially if you'll be changing that site. This is supposed to be a permanent record of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, It didn't work. The checkbox:checked state is not being recoirded in the browser

Comment: The code works. Try the snippet now.

Comment: You don't have jQuery loaded in the codepen. Didn't you see the console error message saying that `$` isn't a function?

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA!!!!! I'm a dufus! God this is embarrassing  lol

Comment: Thanks man. It's been  a long day

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the class on else

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".icheckbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).closest(".gallery-item").addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).closest(".gallery-item").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/zikomagike/edit?html,css,js,console,output

if you want to watch for changes, use `.change()`. This will get triggered even if some other function changes this class and not the input.

Better to add a name attribute and use it in the code: `$( "input[name='chkbox']" )`

HTML

```
<a class="gallery-item" href="#">
  <div class="image">
    <ul class="gallery-item-controls">
      <li>
        <label class="check">
          <input name="chkbox" type="checkbox" class="icheckbox">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</a>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $( "input[name='chkbox']" ).change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(this).closest(".gallery-item").addClass("active");
        } else {
          $(this).closest(".gallery-item").removeClass("active");
        }
      });
    });
```